# How to define where to bind isolated scope properties in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

It is possible to define in which scope's property must assign the attributes defined in a directive?
e.g:

```
angular.module("myMod",[]).
directive("myDir", {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        prop1: "@myProp1",
        prop2: "@myProp2",
    },
    controller: function($scope){
        //Here I have prop1 and prop2 assigned to $scope
        $scope.prop1;
        $scope.prop2;
    },
});
```

But what I want is something like:

```
angular.module("myMod",[]).
directive("myDir", {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        config: { prop1: "@myProp1" }, //This is invalid
        prop2: "@myProp2",
    },
    controller: function($scope){
        //And here, $scope.config.prop1 refers to myProp1
        $scope.config.prop1;
        $scope.prop2;
    },
});
```

I found a partial solution: using controllerAs and bindToController, controllerAs defines an alias to refer the controller and bindToController binds the isolated scope properties to the controller, then I have:

```
$scope.alias.prop1
$scope.alias.prop2
```

But I don't want to bind all properties to controller, because I don't need that. I want to bind some of them to a scope's property, and the rest to another property or directly to the scope.

Why I'm trying to do this?
Because I want to assign:
$scope.config = newConfig;

That is easier than:

```
$scope.prop1 = newProp1;
$scope.prop2 = newProp2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have strong idea but just an idea. What about to use something like this?

```
var cfg = {prop1: '@myProp1'};
angular.module("myMod",[]).
directive("myDir", {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        config: cfg.prop1,
        prop2: "@myProp2",
    },
    controller: function($scope){
        $scope.config;
        $scope.prop2;
    },
});
```

Comment: It is the same to do:
scope: {
  config: { param1: "@myParam1" }
}
and it is not valid

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure if it is possible to do exactly as you wish ([github angular](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/23c8a90d22f7c7b41b5a756b89498ffac828980a/src/ng/compile.js#L1909)), but may be it would fit something like this:

`angular.module("myMod", []).directive("myDir", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            config: "&myConfig",
            prop2: "@myProp2"
        },
        link: function($scope){
            console.log($scope.config(), $scope.prop2);
        }
    }
});`

So in HTML you will be able to define config:

`<div ng-app="myMod">
    <my-dir my-config='{config1: "conf1Val", config2: "conf2Val"}' my-prop2="prop2Val">wver</my-dir>
</div>`

http://jsfiddle.net/xrvpoe4r/2/

Another way is to define convention, for example each config should start with "config-" , and make directive, that will create a new field (object) in scope based on such attributes
For example:
http://jsfiddle.net/xrvpoe4r/4/

Comment: If I define myConfig such as your example, config1 and config2 properties will be ever evaluated with '&' mode (defined in "&myConfig") and it is more verbose. You gave me an idea with your suggestion of "convention" but not entirely understand, can you explain  in more detail?

Comment: Updated my answer
http://jsfiddle.net/xrvpoe4r/4/
Don't sure it's excellent, but may be it would be interesting